# How to compute $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{|x|+xy+|y|}{|x|+|y|}}$

Tags: limits

So I have $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{\frac{|x|+xy+|y|}{|x|+|y|}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{1+\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}}$$

but what to do with this? It seems to be $0$ however, I can't prove it

Comment: $$\left|\frac{|x|+xy+|y|}{|x|+|y|}-1\right|=\left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right|=|x|\frac{|y|}{|x|+|y|}\leqslant|x|\to0$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition. Suppose $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$

$$ \left|\frac{|x|+xy+|y|}{|x|+|y|}-1\right| = \left|\frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}\right| = \frac{\left|xy\right|}{|x|+|y|} \leq |x| $$

And $|x|\to 0$ when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, so the original limit tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the definition is the "sandwich" theorem.

Recall that $-|x|\le x\le|x|$ so:
$$-|x|-|y|\le -|x|\le x\le|x|\le|x|+|y|$$
Then, taking the first, third, and fifth terms, and dividing by $|x|+|y|$ results:
$$-1\le \frac{x}{|x|+|y|}\le 1$$
and also
$$1-y\le 1+\frac{x\,y}{|x|+|y|}\le 1+y$$
But:
$$\lim_{y\to 0} 1-y=\lim_{y\to 0} 1+y=1$$
so
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{|x|+x\,y+|y|}{|x|+|y|}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}1+\frac{x\,y}{|x|+|y|}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $$x=rcos \theta$$ $$y=rsin \theta$$ and we have that:

$\lim_{(x,y) \longrightarrow (0,0)}1+ \frac{xy}{|x|+|y|}= \lim_{r \longrightarrow 0} 1+ \frac{r^2 cos \theta sin\theta}{r (|cos \theta|+ |sin \theta|)}=1$